# TextBox does not exist in the current context in DataGrgid DataRowTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid which on click will show a textbox for user input. I am able to display the details on the textbox. Now I have a Update button inside the datatemplate. Once i click on the update button I want the user input taken and do processing.

This is my xaml code:

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="BlanchedAlmond" Padding="10">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="First Name: " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstName" FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" Text="{Binding UserFirstName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="Last Name: " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtLastName" FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" Text="{Binding UserLastName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Content="Update" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="btnUpdate_Click"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

This is my .cs code:

```
void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string firstName;
        firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    }
```

The txtFirstName.Text is showing `Does Not Exist In The Current Context`

Answer (score 0):

Because it's inside the datatemplate you may have to do something like https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-access-a-control-6039571a

Or use the binding that you already have, just make the mode TwoWay.

{Binding UserFirstName, Mode=TwoWay}